# using the extra space on a gpt hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, formatting

Win7 64 bit.

I have a computer with a 3TB drive. This is the first time I've ever used one that big and didn't know about the gpt format. The disk management app shows 100MB Sytem Reserve, 2047.9GB C: partition, and 746.52GB unallocated. Right clicking this unallocated space does not give me the option to create a new volume. I understand that the Windows installer will not format to a GPT drive. Is there any way to use this extra space?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click disk C: and choose 'Extend volume'. Note that each partition can hold only 2**64 clusters, so if your volume cluster size is very small you can't enlarge your partition further. I guess you should try Partition Magic or PartEd Magic.